# Excel VBA SQL Query to Access to return records between dates

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

Morning all,

I am hoping this is a quick one. I have a query in Excel that requests records between two date points. It returns without errors but also returns unexpected values, seemingly because the date has been swapped around. I am working with the UK date format (dd/mm/yyy).

I have tried passing the date as a date type and a string type, as a datevalue and just the text. I have also tried passing it as yyyymmdd.

In the below example sFromDate is 06/04/2016 (6th April) and sToDate is 12/04/16 (12th April). Dates between June and December are being returned.

```
sSelectedArea = "ThisTMRacf"
sFromDate = DateValue(Sht_SpecificView.Range("D5"))
sToDate = DateValue(Sht_SpecificView.Range("F5"))

Set rex = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT eGain.RecordDate FROM [eGain], [Staff] 
WHERE eGain.Racf = Staff.Racf AND (Staff.TeamManager = '" & sSelectedArea & "' 
OR Staff.CSM = '" & sSelectedArea & "') 
AND eGain.RecordDate BETWEEN #" & sFromDate & "# AND #" & sToDate & "# ;")
```

Is there another way to pass the date so that it doesn't convert?

Comment: As an aside, old-style joins are never pretty and could bite you in the bottom further down the line

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, John. How would you restructure it?

Comment: FROM [eGain] inner join [Staff] on eGain.Racf = Staff.Racf WHERE...

Comment: Thanks John! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting the dates as yyyy/mm/dd worked. Example below.

```
sFromDate = Format(Sht_Dashboard.Range("D5"), "yyyy/mm/dd")
sToDate = Format(Sht_Dashboard.Range("F5"), "yyyy/mm/dd")
```

Answer (score 1):

Might have to be ruthless with this and break the dates down and rebuild...

```
sFromDateY = Year(DateValue(Sht_SpecificView.Range("D5")))
sFromDateM = Month(DateValue(Sht_SpecificView.Range("D5")))
sFromDateD = Day(DateValue(Sht_SpecificView.Range("D5")))
```

Then use

```
AND eGain.RecordDate BETWEEN DateSerial(" & sFromDateY &", "& sFromDateM &", "&sFromDateD &") ...
```

Comment: If it works I don't mind a bit of ruthlessness! Will try shortly and report back.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, John. I managed to utilise a simpler approach. I have posted the answer.